# Cocos 2d draw line doesn't work

Tags: ios, ios4, cocos2d-iphone, ios5

I want to draw line on finger touch in cocos 2d.

```
-(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)inappropriateTouches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [inappropriateTouches anyObject];

    CGPoint currentTouchArea = [touch locationInView:[touch view] ];
    CGPoint lastTouchArea = [touch previousLocationInView:[touch view]];

    currentTouchArea = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:currentTouchArea];
    lastTouchArea = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:lastTouchArea];

    // throw to console my inappropriate touches
    NSLog(@"current x=%2f,y=%2f",currentTouchArea.x, currentTouchArea.y);
    NSLog(@"last x=%2f,y=%2f",lastTouchArea.x, lastTouchArea.y);  

    glColor4f(0.8, 1.0, 0.76, 1.0);
    glLineWidth(6.0f);
    ccDrawLine(currentTouchArea, lastTouchArea);
}
```

I use this code but nothing is drawn on the screen. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All OpenGL drawing you want to do in the draw method. Like this:

```
-(void)draw
{
    if(lastTouchArea != 0)
    {
       glColor4f(0.8, 1.0, 0.76, 1.0);
       glLineWidth(6.0f);
       ccDrawLine(currentTouchArea, lastTouchArea);
       lastTouchArea = 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the screen is cleared each time it is refreshed. To persist the lines, you will have to store an array of points to represent the lines you wish to draw.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : to save a line in a NSMutableArray

```
-(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)inappropriateTouches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touchMyMinge = [inappropriateTouches anyObject];

    CGPoint currentTouchArea = [touchMyMinge locationInView:[touchMyminge view] ];
    CGPoint lastTouchArea = [touchMyMinge previousLocationInView:[touchMyMinge view]];

    // flip belly up. no one likes being entered from behind.
    currentTouchArea = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:currentTouchArea];
    lastTouchArea = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:lastTouchArea];

    // throw to console my inappropriate touches
    NSLog(@"current x=%2f,y=%2f",currentTouchArea.x, currentTouchArea.y);
    NSLog(@"last x=%2f,y=%2f",lastTouchArea.x, lastTouchArea.y);  

   // add my touches to the naughty touch array 
   naughtyTouchArray addObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(currentTouchArea)];
   naughtyTouchArray addObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(lastTouchArea)];
}
```

@implementation DrawMyTouch

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) 
    { }
    return self;
}

-(void)draw
{
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);

    for(int i = 0; i < [naughtyTouchArray count]; i+=2)
    {
        start = CGPointFromString([naughtyTouchArray objectAtIndex:i]);
        end = CGPointFromString([naughtyTouchArray objectAtIndex:i+1]);

        ccDrawLine(start, end);
    }
}


-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    DrawMyTouch *line = [DrawMyTouch node];
    [self addChild: line];
}
```

Hope this help